# Using execvp to execute command line arguments using full path name errors

Tags: c, linux, execvp

I'm pretty new to Linux so please bear with me. I'm trying to execute command line arguments from the terminal, with each argument being the full path of the executable file. So for example, a command line like this:

```
./cmdarguments /Desktop/darren/lab01/c_ex1/a.out
```

would mean that `cmdarguments` is my parent program, and the following command line is a path to a file I wish to execute that simply prints out `hello world`.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int counter;
    
    for(counter = 0; counter < argc; counter++){
        
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0)
        {
            perror("Forking failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid == 0)
        {
            char *args[] = {argv[counter], NULL};
            execvp(args[0], args);
            printf("Command completed.\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        
    }
    exit(0);
    
}
```

I understand that there is a probably a lot missing in my code, and from what I read online I'm only confusing myself more. This is meant to be a simple task only using `fork` and `exec`. Right now, my current output is just `Command completed`, and whatever I use as my second command line arguments seems to have no change to the output, it is always `Command completed`.

Comment: `counter = 0`. `argv[0]` is `./cmdarguments`

Comment: Use a debugger. Check what args you are passing to `execvp` - is it what you expect?

Comment: @KamilCuk okay, so i should start my counter from 1 to take arguments after the parent program which is the 0th argument?

Comment: @kaylum From what I understand the first argument to execvp is meant to be the parent program which should be the 0th argument yes?

Comment: No, that's not the case. Read the [execvp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp). It's pretty clear: "The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed".

Comment: Note that `execvp` will **not** return if it succeeds. So `printf("Command completed.\n");` should be `perror("Command failed");`. Also, don't put a `\n` at the end of the string passed to `perror`, since `perror` will print your message followed by a colon, a description of the error, and a newline character.

Comment: if in doubt *printf* the arguments that will be passed to execve

Answer (score 4):

Some notes on your program:

1. The `exec*` family of functions does not return in case of success. Those functions will *replace your entire process* with the new one specified through the arguments. Those functions only return in case of failure, and the error can be read from `errno`, or through `perror` (which prints a description of `errno`). Possible errors are defined in [the man page `man execvp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3p.html). You should use `perror()` after `exec*()`, to get the error printed.

   Your output is always `Command completed` because your `execvp()` call always fails.
2. The `exec*` family of functions does *not* need to know anything about the "parent" process (parent process means nothing actually since they replace the current process regardless of it being a parent or child of anything). The only arguments are (depending on which variant you use) the new process path, its arguments and environment.
3. The `argv` argument passed to main will always contain the name of the current process in position `0`, and the arguments will follow (until `argc - 1`).
4. The `perror()` function takes a string and then prints it followed by a colon, the description of the error and a newline. You should `perror("x")`, not `perror("x\n")`.
5. If something fails and your program cannot continue, it is usually a good idea to exit with a number *different than `0`*, to indicate failure to the caller (or to you, if you are running it in a shell).
6. Using `exit()` in `main()` is pointless, `return` will have the same effect, since it's the main program. The `exit()` function is useful if you want to terminate the program from within a different function than `main()`.
7. To my knowledge, `/Desktop/darren/lab01/c_ex1/a.out` is not usually a valid path on a normal UNIX system. You usually have `Desktop` inside your home directory. You probably want to use `~/Desktop/...` or `$HOME/Desktop/...` or `/home/yourname/Desktop/...` or even a relative path like `./a.out`.

With the above said, a correct version of your code would be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned counter;
    
    for(counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork failed");
            return 1;
        }
        else if(pid == 0)
        {
            char *args[] = {argv[counter], NULL};
            execvp(args[0], args);

            // OR, equivalent to the above two lines:
            // execlp(argv[counter], argv[counter], NULL);

            fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", argv[counter]);
            perror("execvp failed");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Example output:

```
$ ./cmdarguments ls pwd
cmdarguments x.c
/home/marco/test

$ ./cmdarguments /bin/ls /bin/pwd
cmdarguments x.c
/home/marco/test

$ ./cmdarguments /does/not/exist
/does/not/exist: execvp failed: No such file or directory
```